# How to correct efp() error "invalid type (list) for variable 'data'"?

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, sampling

I have a large(>100,000) single column floating point time-series data. I want to find structural changes within the data with respect to time( in my case index). In-order to do that, I am using R strucchange package. But I'm getting error. I expect to generate the following kind of plot with my dataset
[image]

Here is the code which I'm using:

```
data = read.csv("tst1.csv", header = FALSE)
library(strucchange)

## fit, visualize and test OLS-based CUSUM test
## with a Cramer-von Mises functional
ocus <- efp(data ~ 1, type = "OLS-CUSUM")
sctest(ocus, functional = "meanL2")

## estimate breakpoints
bp <- breakpoints(data ~1)
summary(bp)

plot.ts(data)
lines(bp)
lines(fitted(bp, type = "mean"), col = 2)
```

---

I'm getting following error messages:

```
Loading required package: zoo

Attaching package: ‘zoo’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

as.Date, as.Date.numeric

Loading required package: sandwich
Error in model.frame.default(formula, data = data) : 
invalid type (list) for variable 'data'
Calls: efp -> model.frame -> model.frame.default
Execution halted
```

---

My data tst1.csv looks like:

```
0.6
0.78
0.54
0.96
0.43
1.43
1.03
0.83
0.68
3.23
3.09
2.87
...
```

---

Any help is much more appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where *exactly* do you get the error messages? I would assume in the call to `efp()`. What is the output of `str(data)`?

Comment: @StephanKolassa, When I run the code on terminal using Rscript test.R , I got this error messages. I'm very new in R. I don't know how to get str(data). However, when I typed data on the R console, I get a data frame. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because data is a data frame. In order to put it in the formula correctly, try this:

```
ocus <- efp(V1 ~ 1, data=data,type = "OLS-CUSUM")
```

Comment: @coulminer_I tried your code and I got the following error:Loading required package: zoo

Attaching package: ‘zoo’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    as.Date, as.Date.numeric

Loading required package: sandwich

 OLS-based CUSUM test with mean L2 norm

data:  ocus
S0 = 307.4023, p-value = 0.005

Error in model.frame.default(formula, data = data) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'data'
Calls: breakpoints ... breakpoints.formula -> model.frame -> model.frame.default
Execution halted
----------------------

Comment: that is because you are again using  the data frame called "data" in the formula where a variable is expected. solution is same as in previous case: substitute data with data$V1 also in the part where you  estimate breakpoints, like this: bp <- breakpoints(data$V1 ~1)